# Calling the same LDB with different selection screens

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I have a program that uses the Logical db F1S. That means that it can use an automatic *magical* include with the name DBF1SSEL.

So let's say i have 2 programs that need to use the logical database F1S. Would they be able to have 2 selection screens, or would they all have to use the DBF1SSEL one?

Or how does this automatic name binding-conversion-thingy work? (i'm a java guy learning abap)

Thx, you guys rule!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N.b. I'm not up to scratch on LDBs, have only used them a couple of times.

The selection screen that appears depends on the `NODES` from the LDB that you specify for use in the program, see [SAP docs](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw70ehp3/7.03.19/en-US/4a/43c3225a503f04e10000000a421937/content.htm?no_cache=true). So if your two programs use different sets of nodes, you will potentially get different selection screens (but still built up automatically). I think you can additionally specify manual selection screen elements too.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of calling LDB is through FM `LDB_PROCESS`. It accepts `SELECTIONS` parameter which is used for selection criteria specification.

Consider this sample:

```
* Populate selection-fields
 clear seltab[].
 clear wa_seltab.
 wa_seltab-kind = 'S'.
 wa_seltab-selname = 'CARRID'.
 LOOP AT CARRID INTO wa_carrid.
   MOVE-CORRESPONDING wa_carrid TO wa_seltab.
   APPEND wa_seltab TO seltab.
 ENDLOOP.

* Process the logical database
CALL FUNCTION 'LDB_PROCESS'
 EXPORTING
   ldbname = 'F1S'
   variant = ''
 TABLES
   callback = callback
   selections = seltab[]
   exceptions
 OTHERS = 4.
END-OF-SELECTION.
```